# How do I make an easygui Multi Enter Box?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, easygui

**How do I make an easygui Multienterbox with all of the questions below in one window?**

```
namegui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter your name', title='Name query', default='Gian')
baigui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter your BAI', title='Burns Anxiety Inventory query', default='Gian')
bdcgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter your BDC', title='Burns Depression Checklist query', default='Gian')
yeargui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current year', title='Current Year', default='2011')
monthgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current month', title='Current Month')
daygui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current day', title='Current Day')
time_hourgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current hour', title='Current Hour')
time_minutegui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter current minutes', title='Current Minute')                                
am_pmgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter either am or pm', title='AM OR PM')
```

**I am using Python 2.5.1 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard(10.6).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [EasyGui Tutorial](http://www.ferg.org/easygui/tutorial.html#contents_item_11.4) has a section on using `multienterbox`. You an put all of your field names in a list (`fieldNames = ['Name query','Burns Anxiety inventory query',...]`) and pass it to `multienterbox` along with a window title (`title`) and a message (`msg`):

```
fieldValues = multenterbox(msg,title, fieldNames)
```

If you still need the values in individual fields, you could then unpack your tuple:

```
# include one variable name for each value in fieldValues
namegui, baigui, bdcgui = fieldValues
```

Comment: (fieldNames= ['Year','Month','Day','Time Hour','Time Minute', 'AM or PM'])

log = easygui.multenterbox(msg='Fill in the blanks',title='log', fieldNames)

Comment: That is my best attempt at a working multienterbox. Would u please help make a working example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example

```
def GetNameconfig():
   name = "TestInputValue"
   return name


defaultName = GetNameconfig()
msg = "Enter your personal information"
title = "Credit Card Application"
fieldNames = ["Name","Street Address","City","State","ZipCode"]
fieldValues = [defaultName, "Hauptstr. 1", "", "Germany", ""]
box = eg.multenterbox(msg,title, fieldNames, fieldValues)
print("Reply was: %s" % str(fieldValues))
```